How can I efficiently search in a channel in Slack for iPad without having to type the entire channel name?
I use the Slack app on iPad. I'm browsing a channel. I'd like to search for some text inside that channel. How can I do it efficiently?
The only way I found so far is to click on the search icon on the left bar, write the string to search followed by in:channelname. It's quite tedious to have to write down the channel name. I don't have to do it when accessing Slack via a web browser. I feel I may have missed something in the Slack app.

Reddit user fumo7887 pointed me to a solution:

Tap the channel name banner at the top of the screen and there is a Search button which will only search that channel.

Demo:

